# Html page not loading completely

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

While working with this .html page I found an annoying behavior. The moment I load the page it will load only some portion of the page ,if I refresh it,then loads properly.
Why is this happening ??
I have attached the images along with my html code.

The first image is what I am getting and the second one is the desired one.

This is the first image [image]

and this is what I require

[image]

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1" />
<title>Imperial</title>
<style> 
    .smooth_zoom_preloader {
        background-image: url(zoom_assets/preloader.gif);
    } 
    .smooth_zoom_icons {
        background-image: url(zoom_assets/icons.png);
    } 
</style>

<link href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type='text/css' href='./js-disclaimer/basic.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='./js-disclaimer/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js-disclaimer/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js-disclaimer/basic.js'></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="zoom_assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="zoom_assets/jquery.smoothZoom.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#yourImageID').smoothZoom({
            width: '80%',
            height: '70%',

            /******************************************
            Enable Responsive settings below if needed.
            Max width and height values are optional.
            ******************************************/
            responsive: false,
            responsive_maintain_ratio: false,
            max_WIDTH: '',
            max_HEIGHT: ''
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body style="background:none">

  <!-- home -->
    <!---- menu area--->
    <div class="menu_area"> <img src="./img/logo.png" alt=""> <br>
     <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="worldaboveworld.html" title="world">World above the world</a></li>
        <li><a href="spaces.html">Spaces</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety.html" title="safety">Safety &amp; Security</a></li>
        <li><a href="plan.html">Plans</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="enquiry.html" title="enquiry">Enquiry</a></li>
        <li><a href="address.html" title="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <br>
        <br>
        <li><a href="aboutsdk.html" title="SD">About SD Corp.</a></li>
    <li><a href="img/IE Bro20713 copy.pdf">ebrochure</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="NorthMarker" id="North" style="position:absolute;top:66%;left:18%;width:10px;height:10px; z-index: 99;">
         <img src="img/NorthView.png" id="northview">
      </div>

         <div class="SouthMarker" id="South" style="position:absolute;top:66%;left:97%;width:10px;height:10px; z-index: 99;">
         <img src="img/SouthView.png" id="southview">
      </div>


    <div style="float:left; margin-top:5%; margin-left:5%;"><img id="yourImageID" src="img/plan.jpg" width="86%" height="70%"/> 
        <div class="intermediate" style="display:none;position:absolute;left:0%;top:0%;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);width:100%;height:100%;z-index:104;"></div>
        <div class="northviewpart" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:27%;left:0%;width:100%;height:10px; z-index: 109;">
            <img src="img/40N.jpg" style="width:100%;height:250px;">
        </div>

        <div class="southviewpart" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:27%;left:0%;width:100%;height:10px; z-index: 109;">
            <img src="img/40S.jpg" style="width:100%;height:250px;">
        </div>
        <div id="basic-modal" class="footer_for_plan">© SDCPL 2013. All Rights Reserved&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="basic">Disclaimer</a></div>  
    </div>  


<!-- modal content -->
<div id="basic-modal-content">
  <h3>Disclaimer</h3>
  <p>The content depicted herein is for general information and purely conceptual and is not legal offering nor will it be part of any binding document. The Developer reserves the right to delete, modify or supplement the content at any time for any reason without prior notification.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is loaded perfectly but the issue is with the zoom of the canvas..

Comment: Well considering `#yourImageID` doesnt exist on this page I doubt that has much to do with it.  But good find :)

Comment: @Deryck `<img id="yourImageID" src="img/plan.jpg" width="86%" height="70%"/> `

Comment: also change `<img id="yourImageID" src="img/plan.jpg" width="86%" height="70%"/>` with `<img id="yourImageID" src="img/plan.jpg" style="width:86%; height:70%"/>`

Comment: This code is actually NOT valid, you have 2 closing </div> extra and some <br/> in between <li> tags. First Validate your page might GREATLY improve rendering

Comment: @zzlalani haha apparently using CTRL + F in JSFiddle doesn't produce expected results

Comment: You can use an extension `Validate Document` in google chrome to validate your html. Moreover see possible javascript errors/exceptions in browser `console` by pressing `F12` and then `ESC` key (Chrome).

Comment: Can you give the live website link?

Comment: @ Surijith SM its not yet developed only local copies available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all for the efforts ,however my problem got solved only once I validated the document using chrome validator.

I had used "%" to display the image width and height.I had to put some numeric values(as per need).Now its working fine.

But I am still wondering how can I make it fit to different screen size and resolutions ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is loading of JavaScript files.. Move all script tag at the end. Before closing body tag. hope it heps

Comment: What makes you so sure it's the javascript loading order?

Comment: @ manoj can u explain a bit .I dint get that "Before closing body tag. " part.

Comment: the "#yourImageID" is not yet created when your script executes and hence may be the root of the problem

Comment: then how on refreshing the page loads properly 
I cant understand that

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess (which I'm going to cuz I love gambling) I'd say it has something to do with...

- Loading 3 copies of **jQuery**
- Beginning all of your `href=""`, `src=""` and `url()` attributes with a period

Here are the jQuery instances I found:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js-disclaimer/jquery.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="zoom_assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not 100% sure what the first one is since it's a local file but if it's file name is any indication...it's jQuery.

### Long story short:

Delete this line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js-disclaimer/jquery.js'></script>
```

and delete this line:

```
<script src="zoom_assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can u explain a bit am completely new to these things.

Comment: I love that one. 3 jQuery.  I bet on you.

Comment: I have tried removing those lines ,but sometime it works and sometime it does not

Answer (score 0):

I think the Page is loaded the issue is with the `smoothZoom` zoom, If you see closely the image has been loaded but it is zoomed out completely

also change your

```
<img id="yourImageID" src="img/plan.jpg" width="86%" height="70%"/>
```

with

```
<img id="yourImageID" src="img/plan.jpg" style="width:86%; height:70%"/>
```

**EDIT:**

also your script has three jquery files included, you need to get rid of atleast of the them. select one file that you want to keep and move it to the top

I will suggest you to keep

```
<script src="zoom_assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

move the file to the root and move the line to the top

```
++ <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
-- <script type='text/javascript' src='./js-disclaimer/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js-disclaimer/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js-disclaimer/basic.js'></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

-- <script src="zoom_assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="zoom_assets/jquery.smoothZoom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: no it's not working.TO be honest it is not full proof smetime it loads some time does not.

Comment: yeah I tried ,but with the latest fix the map has gone invisible,hence I had to revert back

Answer (score 0):

```
use this 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
instead of all these three...
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js-disclaimer/jquery.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="zoom_assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When script loads its unable to find the div id you have created because you are loading a img before the img dom elemnet is created